# Java - List<String> printing \n instead of showing a line break

Tags: java, string, swing, text

I have a .txt file reader, which reads individuals lines of a file and stores them in a `List<String>` which I then display on a JTextArea. Some of the lines contain `\n`, because I wanted specific breaking when displaying. However, when I do display the code, the `\n`are shown instead of breaking the line as they usually do.

I tried replacing the `\n`'s with linebreaks by placing the code `str.replaceAll( "\\\\n", System.lineSeperator());` in the while loop, before `list.add(str);` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

To reiterate, I simply need a way to change the `\n`'s to linebreaks. Any help would be much appreciated.

The code for the .txt reader is below.

```
static void parseStringArray(final String filePath, List<String> list){
            try {
                InputStream input = Text.class.getResourceAsStream(filePath);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                String str;
                while((str = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    list.add(str);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**Edit - I have updated the post to include a bit more code.

The List I send in as an argument is initialized before the method. It is

```
protected static List<String> textfiles = new ArrayList<String>();
```

An example of a line from the .txt file is

*Welcome!\n\n If you wish to proceed, please type the password below.\nEnjoy your stay!*

The code to display this text is below. (Pardon formatting)

```
Timer teletypeTimer = null;
public static void animateTeletype(final JTextArea displayArea)
    {
        final String[] s = new String[1];
        s[0] = "";
        final int[] i = new int[2];
        i[0] = 0;
        i[1] = 0;
        teletypeTimer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(i[0]==0)
                    displayArea.setText("");
                s[0] = TTqueue[i[1]].substring(i[0], i[0]+1);
                i[0]++;
                displayArea.append(s[0]);
                if(displayArea.getText().equals(TTqueue[i[1]]))
                {
                    i[1]++;
                    if(TTqueue[i[1]] !=null)
                    {
                        teletypeTimer.stop();
                        i[0] = 0;
                        timerRestart(5000, teletypeTimer);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Arrays.fill(TTqueue, null);
                        complete=true;
                        teletypeTimer.stop();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        teletypeTimer.start();
      }
```

Comment: I think it would help to see more of your code. Please consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: I think the \n is written literally in his file. We need the input files and the replace code I think to see what's going on.

Comment: `str.replaceAll( "\\\\n", System.lineSeperator())` (or even better `str.replace( "\\n", System.lineSeperator())` to avoid explicit regex escaping) should create new string with replaced `\n`. Are you sure you are using result of this method? Maybe you forgot to store it back to `str` reference (like `str = str.replace...`) so `str` still contains its original string? Anyway this is only way around. If I ware you I would try to focusing on preventing this problem rather than creating workaround solution.

Comment: @Nick Vanderhoven That's right, the \n is in the .txt file.

Comment: @ThomasRichmond How was the file created with '/n'? Do you have control over it?

Comment: @MordechayS I'm not writing to the file, just reading it. I place the \n's in the file originally.

Comment: @ThomasRichmond If the file is created by you - don't insert line-breaks by yourself. Just go to a new line - the rest will be taked care of.

Comment: @ThomasRichmond What MordechayS said, why don't you try adding line breaks ware you're currently putting `\n`? Otherwise, try the suggestions by Pshemo.

Comment: @MordechayS the problem then is that I want to be able to store many of these prompts in a single .txt file. So I can't line break.

Comment: @ThomasRichmond Thats probably the problem you should by asking about. :) Why can't you?

Comment: @MordechayS Essentially, I have several prompts. I need to display them at different times, but want to store them on the same find. Each one needs line breaks at certain points (See post edit).

Comment: @ThomasRichmond serialize an ArrayList of the prompts, then deserialize and use the desired index.

Comment: @MordechayS I'll start looking into that. Cheers!

Comment: I don't see where you do the replace all in your code. Can you include that code snippet? I also think you forgot to reassign the result of the replace all call to your string variable.

Comment: @ThomasRichmond any conclusions?

Comment: @MordechayS got it working now. I tried Pshemo's suggestion finally (I was away for a while after posting) and after a bit of tinkering, it seems to have done the trick. I will keep looking into serialization, and see what else I can find to improve the system. Cheers for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I switched `replaceAll()` with `replace()` and worked with Pshemo and Nick Vanderhoven's points. I added the line of code `str = str.replace("\\n", System.lineSeparator());` as suggested by Pshemo, and that's done the trick. Cheers!